# jquery scrollpane vertical bar height

Tags: jquery, scrollpane

I have a div 300px in height but i dont want the vertical scrollbar/track to be 300px. How do i set the height of the scrollbar/track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a property you can set. But you can fake it with this:

http://13thparallel.com/archive/dhtml-scrollbars/